# Solving multiple equations that are equal to each other

Tags: equation-solving

I have a set of 4 equations that are all equal.

```
    400 (T1 - 283) == 12200 (T2 - T1) == 3560 (Ts - T2) == 2340 Exp[-710.45/Ts] (333 - Ts)
```

I've tried using Solve and NSolve to solve this system, but it's not working. Solve gives "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help."
NSolve gives the same input back as the output. Reduce runs without stopping.

To be honest I'm just really confused about what it even means when you have multiple sets of equations that are all equal to each other. Are there sufficient equations to solve for all the unknowns? Are these equations even considered independent?

(First time posting here, I apologise for being totally clueless, if I'm asking the wrong questions or providing insufficient information) Many thanks for the kind soul(s) who may help me out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The system of equations presented are transcendental equations. `Solve` and `NSolve` generally doesn't work with these types. Instead, `FindRoot` can be used.

First, eliminate variables `T1` and `T2`.

```
eqns = {400 (T1 - 283) == 12200 (T2 - T1), 
   12200 (T2 - T1) == 3560 (Ts - T2), 
   3560 (Ts - T2) == 2340 Exp[-710.45/Ts] (333 - Ts)};
tsEqn = Eliminate[eqns , {T1, T2}];
(*E^(-710.45/Ts) (727389. + 108580. E^(710.45/Ts)) Ts == 
 E^(-710.45/Ts) (2.42221*10^8 + 3.07281*10^7 E^(710.45/Ts))*)
```

Then, solve the transcendental equation using `FindRoot` to get `Ts`.

```
tsSol = FindRoot[tsEqn, {Ts, 3}]
(*{Ts -> 302.509}*)
```

Now, `solving` the first two equations with `tsSol`, we get `T1` and `T2` as `300.036` and `300.595`, respectively.

**Edit:**

Instead of eliminating `T1` and `T2` variables to get a single equation and then using `FindRoot`, we can directly use `FindRoot` for all the equations directly.

```
FindRoot[eqns, {T1, 1}, {T2, 1}, {Ts, 1}]
(*{T1 -> 300.036, T2 -> 300.595, Ts -> 302.509}*)
```

Answer (score 5):

Amplifying on @AnjanKumar's answer

```
eqns = {400 (T1 - 283) == 12200 (T2 - T1), 12200 (T2 - T1) == 3560 (Ts - T2), 
    3560 (Ts - T2) == 2340 Exp[-710.45/Ts] (333 - Ts)} // Rationalize;
tsEqn = Eliminate[eqns, {T1, T2}];

sol1 = Reduce[{tsEqn, Ts > 0}, Ts, Reals] // ToRules

(*  {Ts -> Root[{-242220537 + 
             727389*#1 + 
             E^(14209/(20*#1))*
               (-30728140 + 108580*#1) & , 
         302.50906126910556200203256760\
     314296316865`20.602059973044152}]}  *)
```

Verifying the partial solution

```
tsEqn /. sol1 // FullSimplify

(*  True  *)

sol = {sol1, Reduce[(eqns /. sol1) // FullSimplify, {T1, T2}] // ToRules} // 
   Flatten // N[#, 10] &

(*  {Ts -> 302.5090613, T1 -> 300.0363027, T2 -> 300.5948700}  *)
```

Verifying the complete solution

```
eqns /. sol

(*  {True, True, True}  *)
```

**EDIT:** The rationalized equations can be solved directly with [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)

```
sol = Reduce[eqns, {Ts, T12, T2}, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True] //
   N[#, 10] & // ToRules

(*  {T1 -> 300.0363027, Ts -> 302.5090613, T2 -> 300.5948700}  *)

eqns /. sol

(*  {True, True, True}  *)
```